# While loop with nextLine condition

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a method for a class that works with database data. I'm trying to do a `System.out.println`for my array `values[]` using a `while loop` and a `.nextLine`  I was hoping someone could provide some suggestions.  I know there are other ways to do this but I was hoping not to use any additional variables.  If that's not possible I totally understand, but I figured someone here must know of a way.  Thanks for the help and here's my method

```
    public void query(String table,String... column)
{
    System.out.println("name of table is: " + table);
    System.out.println("column values are: ");

    while(column[].nextLine())
        {
            System.out.println(column.nextLine());
        }

}//end method query()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an *enhanced-for* (also called *for-each*) loop:

```
for (String s : column) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Or a normal `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(column[i]);
}
```

If you use a `while` you will have to keep count of indices:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < column.length) {
    System.out.println(column[i]);
    i++;
}
```

**Note:**

Remember that `column` is an array: `String[] column`.

Comment: for-each seems like the most elegant solution thanks for the help your answer was the most comprehensive.  Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is the most elegant. Use it if you don't need to keep count of indices/positions.

Answer (score 3):

`nextLine()` is a `Scanner`'s method, not a `String`'s. If you alreay have an array of `String`s, you can just loop over them with a (enhanced) `for` loop:

```
public void query(String table, String... column) {
    System.out.println("name of table is: " + table);
    System.out.println("column values are: ");

    for (Strinc c : column) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: just for note `column` isn't a String reference, it is similar to `String[]`

Comment: @JigarJoshi and indeed, I treat it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

`nextLine()` is not a method for an array. Not only that, you used it incorrectly. You should have done this (if these methods were to exist): `while (column.hasNextLine())`

Assuming you would like to use a while loop to print your String array:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < column.length)
{
    System.out.println(column[i]);
    i++; // increment the index
}
```

Or you could use a [for-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) loop (or "enhanced-for" loop, whatever it's called):

```
for (String c : column) {
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Or even a classic for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(column[i]);
}
```